# Detect system language change in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

We can use following code to know when the system language change in Windows Form - [Form.InputLanguageChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.inputlanguagechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string _language = "";
InputLanguageChanged += new InputLanguageChangedEventHandler( (sender, e) =>
{
      language = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.LayoutName;
});
```

What is WPF equivalent of `Form.InputLanguageChanged`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the code as follow to detect keyboard language change in WPF

```
string language = "";
System.Windows.Input.InputLanguageManager.Current.InputLanguageChanged += 
       new    InputLanguageEventHandler((sender, e) =>
{
   language = e.NewLanguage.DisplayName;
});
```

Note: there is no need to detect system UI language change as it requires logoff/logon which in turn will force all applications to restart (Check  Hans Passant comment for [How To Detect Language Changes While Runtime ? (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814500/how-to-detect-language-changes-while-runtime-c)

Comment: Could the InputLanguageManager be used to set the input language on the OSK?  We are developing an app for a touch screen in WPF/.NET 4 and need to have the OSK open up in the correct language...  We are changing the current thread culture on the fly as well, but we're using a custom localization solution.  The only piece left is to get the keyboard to sync up, and if I can't get that working we will have to look into third party keyboards...

Answer (score 3):

Hope [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/wpf/thread/ed9f92e4-c6ba-471e-9dbf-0180952d927d) helps. You have to use [InputLanguageManager.InputLanguageChanging Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputlanguagemanager.inputlanguagechanged%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which occurs when a change of input language is initiated. It should be as below.

```
InputLanguageManager.Current.InputLanguageChanged += new InputLanguageEventHandler(Current_InputLanguageChanged);
```

And here is more details that I found interesting. [WPF Localization - On-the-fly Language Selection](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/10/30/wpf-localization-on-the-fly-language-selection.aspx)