# How To Detect Language Changes While Runtime ? (C#)

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to detect when the user is changing his language on the keyboard.
For example, I want to know if the user is using English, and then changing the language to French.
I want to detect this change from all the active threads. I mean that I want to know when that change happens in the OS, And not in some specific thread..
I'm using C# language.(Console Application)

Can Anyone help me to figure it out? I will be glad to some help..
Thank You.

Comment: The user changed his keyboard layout, not his language and not his CurrentCulture.  Windows will keep talking English to him.  Changing the language requires a logout+login and the Ultimate edition of Windows with the proper MUI pack installed.  At which point you'll be talking French as well.  Responding to this from a console mode app is a lost cause anyway.

Comment: @HansPassant, I meant to the same thing that happend wehn you press Alt + Shift on your keyboard.. In this case it's a lost cause too? and if so, why?

Answer (score 1):

If you develop using WinForms use [InputLanguageChanging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.inputlanguagechanging.aspx) event

Comment: Actually i'm using Console Application. Do you have some example for console application?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the current keyboard layout: [How to determine the current input language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951067/how-to-determine-the-current-input-language)

This is how you change it: [Change Keyboard Layout for Other Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263276/change-keyboard-layout-for-other-process)

Comment: That is not the question.

Comment: since? i mean Aviv may focus more on detecting the **change** of input language in the OS, I'm not sure whether you get further than what is described in the first stackoverflow link I posted...